# How to search for non-D&D-related questions?

Tags: discussion, support, search

I often want to see non-D&D related questions when searching on the site, but there's such an overwhelmingly large number of D&D related products (including Pathfinder and Starfinder) to exclude I sometimes get this warning when manually excluding then whilst searching:

[image: an attempt to manually exclude all D&D products from a site search, using the minus sign, resulting in a warning transcribed below]

> Please shorten this text to 240 characters or less (you are currently using 331 characters)

*n.b. the `ranger` tag shown, in the screenshot, is unclosed as I first spotted the warning when editing an existing search*

How can I exclude these products quickly and easily from searches?

Comment: Follow-up question: What do I do to get the error message corrected to say 'Please shorten this text to 240 characters or _fewer_'?

Comment: @Kirt it's ok to say that, [Tom Scot said so](https://youtu.be/2qT8ZYewYEY).

Comment: Tom Scott said "if the recipient...isn't trying to decipher what you're saying, then talk however the hell you want".  That's fine for informal spoken communication, but I have a higher standard for written English in a formal notice from a professional company than 'as long as you can understand what they are trying to say, it's fine'.  One site-specific ['reason to edit'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) is "to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes".  By Tom Scott's standard, as long as it was understood, it's not wrong.  YMMV.

Comment: I think there's no ambiguity here in less Vs fewer. It's also an easy fix, so they may listen and do it quickly. The meme is deprecated but feels like this [sorta thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/175002)...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Wildcards to the rescue!

You can use wildcards as per the [search help page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/searching#:%7E:text=Use%20wildcard%20searches%20to%20broaden%20results%3B%20add%20an%20asterisk%20(*)%20anywhere%20in%20the%20word%2C%20like%20encour*%20or%20Ex*nge.):

> "Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk (*) anywhere in the word, like encour* or Ex*nge."

It's [not properly documented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380471/please-can-we-document-how-tags-and-wild-cards-interact-in-the-help-center) but you can do this within a tag. This will exclude all the products mentioned, as far as I can tell:

```
-[dnd-*] -[adnd-*] -[dungeons-and-dragons] -[pathfinder-*] -[starfinder]
```

You'll need to manually enter this as the wildcards are not preserved, and will expand out again (I suspect this is how you got into your original pickle with character lengths).

[image: a successful search page showing all matching tags from the wildcards used above]

There you go, a whole 9 questions to look over, vs the 441 without those products excluded.

---

Honourable mentions to `-[odnd]` which might suggest using `-[*dnd*]` as well as changing to use `[*finder*]` to exclude [lorefinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lorefinder) and [ponyfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ponyfinder), however as there are so few questions under those tags and  leading wildcards [often upset indexed database tables](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server), I've chose to exclude them from the above advice.

Comment: I dropped the image size one level, it was longer vertically than my screen. The change did not affect mobile view and is readable without scrolling on desktop now.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thanks, I hadn't noticed an issue as I haven't gotten to a desktop this weekend. It's a shame they can't load a higher resolution one for mobile, responsively.

Comment: Going through my list of ignored tags I'm seeing that you are missing [tag:odnd] as another dnd tag.

Comment: If you replace `-[pathfinder-*] -[starfinder]` with `-[*finder*]` you can make the query shorter while also picking up the tags [tag:lorefinder] and [tag:ponyfinder] which based on the description are dnd related products.

Comment: @WheatWizard those are honourable mentions, but I don't think significant enough number for me to worry about them on the whole

Comment: You can save this in a filter and then later change [ranger] to something else that you want to search for. It's faster and filters just seem to work better with long tag searches.

Comment: @Laurel what's a filter? (I kid, I've hear did them, never saw a reason to use them though. Maybe this is it?) Want to post an alternative answer?

Comment: The new `[one-dnd-playtest]` tag is not filtered out by the main query, although `[*dnd*]` in the footnote catches it.

Answer (score -2):

### Create a new filter (not currently working)

There is an option to create a filter from a search, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of a search for many tags, and the custom filters card shown with a red freehand circle. Instruction below.]

This can be accessed on a keyboard by tabbing through the tags until you reach a button labeled/named 'Filter'. Then you can click or tab to the textbox containing the searched for tags, and delete any tags not relevant to the filter (in my case, I deleted [spell-resistance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spell-resistance)).

[image: Modal Dialog allowing you to name the filter. The keyboard will be focused in the 'Filter Title' input.]

Unfortunately you cannot make an exclusively negative filter:

> Tag queries cannot be exclusively negative.

Comment: I added this answer as a placeholder given this is close to working and I don't want to delete my lovely screenshots